# Excel VBA Sub to Copy Sheet Not returning to Sub after Cells.Replace statement

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I am writing a subroutine to copy a worksheet from one workbook to another. It needs to replace the spreadsheet of the same name in the "to" workbook.  There may be formulas in other sheets in the "to" workbook that references cells on the sheet to be refreshed.

I have already have one version implemented by copying all the cells from the "from" worksheet to the "to" worksheet.  But I would rather do it by copying the sheet as a whole.
The approach is to:

1. Copy the worksheet, and Excel will automatically assign a new name
   since the original sheet still exists.
2. Update the formulas in all sheets to reference the new sheet using Cells.Replace
3. Delete the old version of the sheet in the "to" workbook
4. Rename the new sheet to the original name and Excel will handle the renames in the formulas

I have the following code written, but it appears to exit the routine after the Cells.replace statement.  The statement works; the formulas are updated in the 1st sheet only.  It does NOT update the formulas in the subsequent sheets.  The statements to delete the old sheet and rename the new sheet are not executed.  If I manually perform the steps after the routine exits, it would work as expected.

What is wrong with the Cells.Update statement such that it executes correctly, but doesn't return to continue the routine?

```
Sub TestReplaceSheets2()

Dim ws_to As Worksheet, ws_from As Worksheet
Dim wb_to As Workbook
Dim iSht As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim newName As String, oldName As String
Dim sTestb As String, sTesta As String
Dim bTest As Boolean

    Set ws_from = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("01-18-2023")
    Set ws_to = Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("01-18-2023")
    
    Set wb_to = ws_to.Parent
    oldName = ws_to.Name
    
    sTestb = wb_to.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Formula 'For verification purposes only
    
    iSht = ws_to.Index
    
    ws_from.Copy After:=wb_to.Sheets(iSht)
    
    newName = wb_to.Sheets(iSht + 1).Name
    
    For Each ws In wb_to.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> oldName And ws.Name <> newName Then
          ws.Cells.Replace What:=ws_to.Name, Replacement:=newName, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        End If

'       It never makes it here - it updates the formulas in the 1st ws , but not the 2nd

    Next ws
    
    ws_to.Delete
    wb_to.Sheets(newName).Name = oldName
    
    sTesta = wb_to.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Formula 'For verification purposes only
    
    bTest = sTesta = sTestb 'For verification purposes only

End Sub
```

Comment: Change the `Worksheets` to `wb_to.Worksheets`?

Comment: Thanks GSerg, I made that correction, but is still stops after the first worksheet's Replace.

Comment: Do you have `Worksheet_Change` handlers in `wb_to`?

Comment: No, I don't have any thing in the events for the wb_to.  I created a new workbook, with two blank sheets, and simply added a formula to each in cell A1:  "='01-18-2023'!B3".  In the `from_ws` sheet, I do have code in the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` event (but nothing in the Worksheet_Change event).

Comment: Do you have an `On Error` handler somewhere outside? In the sub that calls `TestReplaceSheets2()` perhaps?

Comment: I was testing this calling just `TestReplaceSheets2()`.   But I both completely rebooted my PC and added a `On Error Goto 0` statement at the beginning and now it is working fine.  Thank you so much for all the time you took helping me!  I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to GSerg I was able to get the following working for Replacing a Sheet:

```
Function ReplaceSheets(ws_from As Worksheet, ws_to As Worksheet, Optional Compare As Boolean) As Boolean

Dim wb_to As Workbook
Dim iSht As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim copiedName As String, oldName As String

'The approach is to:
'
'1) Copy the worksheet, and Excel will automatically assign a new name since the original sheet still exists.
'2) Update the formulas in all sheets to reference the new sheet using Cells.Replace
'3) Delete the old version of the sheet in the "to" workbook
'4) Rename the new sheet to the original name and Excel will handle the renames in the formulas

    Set wb_to = ws_to.Parent
    
    oldName = ws_to.Name
    
    iSht = ws_to.Index
    
    ws_from.Copy After:=wb_to.Sheets(iSht)
    
    copiedName = wb_to.Sheets(iSht + 1).Name
    
    For Each ws In wb_to.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> oldName And ws.Name <> copiedName Then
          ws.Cells.Replace What:=ws_to.Name, Replacement:=copiedName, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        End If
    Next ws
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws_to.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    wb_to.Sheets(copiedName).Name = oldName
    
    If Compare Then
        ReplaceSheets3 = CompareWorksheets(ws_from, wb_to.Sheets(oldName))
    Else
        ReplaceSheets3 = True
    End If

End Function


Function CompareWorksheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, Optional alert As Boolean) As Boolean
Dim ldiff As Long, lrow1 As Long, lrow2 As Long
Dim i As Integer, icol1 As Integer, icol2 As Integer
Dim bdiff As Boolean

    CompareWorksheets = True
    bdiff = False

    icol1 = GetLastColWithData(ws1)
    lrow1 = GetLastRowWithData(sht:=ws1, Method:=3)
    icol2 = GetLastColWithData(ws2)
    lrow2 = GetLastRowWithData(sht:=ws2, Method:=3)
    
    If icol1 <> icol2 Or lrow1 <> lrow2 Then Exit Function
    
    For i = 1 To icol1
        ldiff = CompareColumns(Range(ws1.Cells(1, i), ws1.Cells(lrow1, i)), Range(ws2.Cells(1, i), ws2.Cells(lrow1, i)))
        If ldiff > 0 Then
            bdiff = True
            CompareWorksheets = False
            If alert Then
                MsgBox ("Difference found in Row " & ldiff & ", Column " & i)
            Else
               Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If alert And Not bdiff Then
        MsgBox ("Sheets Match - No Differences found")
    End If
    
End Function
```